# derivative of the polynomial in a linked list

Tags: c++

For some reason when i am trying to do my derivative it just does a derivative of the one item not the whole polynomial.

```
struct term{
    double coef;
    unsigned deg;
    struct term * next;
    };
```

I have a struct and then also a class Polynomial with deep copy constructor and = constructor.
In a private class i have a `term* ptr`

here is my code for the derivative

```
void Polynomial::derivative (Polynomial *p){
    term *x;
    if ( ptr == NULL)
        return ;
    term *temp;
    temp = ptr;
    while (temp != NULL){
       if ( ptr == NULL){
            ptr = new term ;
            x = ptr ;
        }
        else{
            x -> next = new term ;
            x = x -> next ;
        }
        x-> coef = temp -> coef * temp -> deg;
        x-> deg = temp -> deg - 1;
        temp = temp -> next;

    }
    ptr=x;
}
```

so when i try to derivative of `3x^4 + 3x^4 + 6x^7 + 3x^4 + 3x^4 + 6x^7 + 2x^9` i get `18x^8`

I was looking over the code and have no idea why does it do that for just the last term, since it is a while loop and should go from beginning till NULL and do the derivative.

Comment: You may wish to consider returning a Polynomial populated with the derivative of this one. I.e. don't xform this one. Just walk it, adding terms to the return polynomial as you compute them from this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the last term because of these two lines:

in your else condition:

```
x = x -> next
```

and your final assignment:

```
ptr = x;
```

Consequently, this also leaks memory, since all those pretty terms you allocated prior are now in the ether. You were leaking the old ones anyway, so this really needs a rethink regardless.

I strongly recommend that since your Polynomial class supports full copy construction and assignment operation, you create a *new* derivative polynomial *from* this one, and return *that*. if the caller wants this one transformed they can `poly = poly.derivative();` themselves.

Example of derivative generator (as opposed to transformer). And as a bonus, eliminates all constant terms when generating the derivative.

```
Polynomial Polynomial::derivative() const
{
    Polynomial poly;

    const term *p = ptr;
    while (p)
    {
        if (p->deg != 0) // skip constant terms 
        {
            // add term to poly here (whatever your method is called)
            poly.addTerm(p->coef * p->deg, p->deg-1);
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return poly;
}
```

This allows this kind of generation: (note p1 is unchanged by `derivative()`):

```
Polynomial p1;
... populate p1...
Polynomial p2prime = p1.derivative();
```

And for something really enjoyable:

```
Polynomial p1;
... populate p1...
Polynomial p2prime2 = p1.derivative().derivative();
```

Anyway, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't see whats wrong with that ptr=x as ptr is replaced with x which is the whole polynomial derivative, and x=x->next goes to the next term

Comment: @JackF What does x point to after the *second* term is is created, specifically immediately *after* `x = x->next` is executed in the else clause?

Comment: @JackF yup. which is at the tail of the list (we just linked it prior to moving `x`). Thus when this is finished `ptr` will be set to the *last* node allocated. That would be *precisely* what your output is indicating as well.

Comment: @JackF seriously consider writing a spin of this that *generates* a new polynomial that is the derivative of this one. the code will be brain-dead-simple, and honestly this has at least two nasty memory leaks as is. It is worth considering imho.

Comment: how would that be different though? you still have to go through the terms and save it into a new linked list. Just the return type is different or what?

Comment: @JackF Glad it helped. I've seen your posts on this subject for other questions, and you seem to have a pretty good grasp on the other operators (*, +, -, etc.) returning generated polynomial. This should be no different. So long as your copy-ctor and assign-op are well tested for leaks and strong, this should be pretty easy stuff for you.

Comment: I guess i was kind of confused with the operators and this derivative, i though they were much different, but the return type is the same though, now i see it. Now i just have to do mergesort on the polynomial, thats gonna be a pain...

Comment: @JackF It won't be near the pain you think it may so long as you sort your terms as they're inserted. In doing so, terms being inserted with like-degree can simply update the existing term by adding/subtracting the incoming coefficient to the exiting term. If a matching degree is not found (you can stop searching as soon as `t->next` is NULL or has a lower degree than the incoming term), insert the new term at that location. Your term list stays sorted, and merging two polys becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
PolyNodeN* makeDerivate(PolyNodeN* poly)
{
    PolyNodeN* head = new PolyNodeN();
    PolyNodeN* tmp = new PolyNodeN();
    int a = poly->exp;

    int * results = new int[a];
    int * exponents = new int[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        results[i] = exponents[i] = 0;
    }
    for (poly; poly != nullptr; poly = poly->next)
    {
        results[poly->exp - 1] = poly->koef*poly->exp;
        exponents[poly->exp - 1] = poly->exp - 1;
    }
    head = new PolyNodeN(exponents[a - 1], results[a - 1]);
    tmp = head;

    for (int i = a - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp->next= new PolyNodeN(exponents[i], results[i],tmp);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    return head;
}
```

which derivate ? simple ...

```
PolyNodeN* makeDerivate2(PolyNodeN* poly,int ext)
{
    PolyNodeN* temp = new PolyNodeN();
    temp = temp->makeDerivate(poly);
    for (int i = ext-1; i > 0; i--)
        temp = temp->makeDerivate2(temp, i);
    return temp;
}
```